# How compatible are standard and web edition (backup and mirroring)

Tags: sql-server-2008, backup, restore, mirroring

Long story short. Let us say I have 3 different database servers, one SQL Server 2008 Standard and 2 SQL Server 2008 Web edition.

Will the following hold true?

1. Can I backup and restore between 2008 standard and 2008 web edition without compatibility issues?
2. Can I mirror the 2008 standard to a 2008 web edition? The web edition would only subscribe.

I would test if I could, but won't buy licenses for the servers until I know it is possible.

Thanks!

Comment: As long as you have the same **version** (2008), the backups are compatible across all editions from Express through Datacenter (everything - excluding the Compact Edition which is a totally different story).

Comment: Thanks. And by 2008, does R2 qualify as well?

Comment: **2008** and **2008 R2** are **different** version! SQL Server 2008 is version **10.00.x**, while SQL Server 2008 R2 is **10.50.x**. Those are **NOT** compatible! You can restore a backup from a SQL Server 2008 database onto 2008 R2 - but you can never go back down to 2008 again